# Is there an optimized way to perfrom repeated sampling in Python, similar to `rep_sample_n` in R/dplyr?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, statsmodels

I'm looking for an optimized method of creating sampling distributions in Python, similar to [`rep_sample_n`](https://infer.tidymodels.org/reference/rep_sample_n.html) in `dplyr`. Currently, I am using `df.sample` inside a list comprehension (`pd.concat([df.sample(size) for n in range(N)])`), which is syntactically intuitive, but quite slow when the number of samples increases. Most of the options I have seen here involve either a for loop or list comprehension.

Here is an example that also keeps track of the sample replicate number for clarity:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': range(3)})

sample_size = 2
replicates = 5

pd.concat([
    df.sample(sample_size).assign(replicate=rep)
    for rep in range(replicates)
])
```

Output:

```
   value  replicate
0      0          0
1      1          0
2      2          1
0      0          1
2      2          2
1      1          2
2      2          3
0      0          3
1      1          4
0      0          4
```

Comment: Do you want a `size x N` result dataframe? Your code produces a `(N*size) x 1` result.

Comment: @jlgarcia I added an example of what I'm expecting the output to look like.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code output, which produces a `N*size x 1` array, I think you can rather than concatenating a single value through a loop, just pre-generate all your sample-indexes and then index your `dataframe`:

```
import numpy as np

indexes = np.random.choice(df.index, size=replicates * sample_size) 
df.iloc[indexes].assign(replicate=np.repeat(range(replicates), sample_size))
```

output:

```
   value  replicate
2      2          0
1      1          0
1      1          1
0      0          1
2      2          2
2      2          2
1      1          3
0      0          3
2      2          4
0      0          4
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this is definitely a lot faster. I think it is a bit less intuitive and I'm not sure it  would extend to resampling with replacement. Although, based on this, I think a fruitful approach could be to create just the index in the list comprehension and avoid calling `sample` multiple times (maybe that's the slowdown) and then use `iloc` like you did with the indexes in the end. I will try that later today, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a quite effective solution that still retains somewhat clear syntax and the possibility of control replacement during the sampling:

```py
pd.concat([
    df.loc[np.random.choice(df.index, sample_size)].assign(replicate=rep)
    for rep in range(replicates)
])
```

And ~50X faster than the original in this one test:

[image]

Although I still think the syntax still leaves much to desire, so I opened a feature request to make this possible in pandas directly https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/54714